# How many leaves will this tree have?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

*I'm sorry in advance if this question is not appropriate. I'm no expert in graph theory or in combinatorics, but I've stumbled on this question while working on something else; I'll appreciate any input about it.*

I'm going to grow a tree with the following algorithm.

1. Create a variable $i$ as a counter, that will start at $0$. Start with a single white vertex, which will be the root.
2. Increment the counter $i$ by 1.
3. From each lowest white vertex, create $m$ downgoing white children vertices, numbered $1$ through $m$. (All the new vertices have the same height wrt the root: the height is equal to $i$. Also, the root has no number assigned to it.)
4. From each of these new children vertices, follow the path back to the root. If the number assigned to this new child vertex already appears $k$ times in the path back to the root, not including the new vertex itself, remove the vertex from the tree.
5. Turn black each of these new children vertices whose number is congruent to $i$ modulo $m$.
6. Repeat steps 2-5, until you can't create any more vertices.

**How many (total, black and white) leaves will this tree have?**

Just to make sure the process is clear, here is the image [image: here is the image] for the final tree in the case $m=3, k=2$ **(correction: the rightmost black 3 in the 3rd row should not be there)**. The total number of leaves in this case is <s>33</s> **32**. Sorry for the very bad quality of this tree.

Comment: In your diagram, on the $i=2$ row, the black vertex on the left should not be there. The reason is that if you trace back to the root, you get itself (2), then its parent (2) then the un-numbered root -- that is, its number appears $k$ times, so "remove the vertex from the tree."  The formula arrived at may be simpler (or may be harder) if you follow the rules precisely.

Comment: @MarkFischler Rule 4 says "$k$ times, not including the new vertex".

Comment: @MarkFischler You're right, sorry, I edited the question. In fact, the error was in the description of the algorithm, rather than the image.

Comment: I wrote some Python code to count such leaves: https://repl.it/repls/LikableRoyalProfessional. You can check it to verify if my code has errors, but it says that for your $m=3, k=2$ case, the number of leaves is $32$. I tried entering the values into the OEIS by listing the values by diagonals/antidiagonals, and nothing came up. I wrote the output as sequences, which you can view as paths to the leaves.

Comment: @KevinLong You're right. 32 is correct. My manually-done tree has an extra (incorrect) [3, 3, 3] leaf. I will edit the post.

Comment: I came up with a more memory-efficient Python code, which searches depth-first: https://repl.it/repls/ExternalSafeMachinelanguage I'm currently running $m=5, k=4$ since ~1h, so, yes, the number does increase quite fast. A rough upper bound on the number of white leaves is $(m-1)^(m*k)$ (at each step, only m-1 white vertices are created for each white vertex; this doesn't take into account point 4 though). I have a gut feeling this may be an upper bound even on the total number of leaves, but I have no explanation for that.

Comment: Typo in the previous formula: the estimate is $(m-1)^{mk}$

Comment: I found that this question is very closely related to a problem known as the Dinner-Diner matching problem. The number of white leaves for $k=1,2,3,4$ are given by the sequences A000166, A000459, A059073, A059074 of the OEIS, and the number of white leaves for $k=5$ can be extracted from A059062. This does not answer the question but in fact solves the problem that made me post this question.